# Get some string before " not in all lines python

Tags: python, text, split, line

I have such entries in a txt file with such structure:

```
Some sentence.
Some other "other" sentence.
Some other smth "other" sentence.
```

In original:

```
Камиш-Бурунський залізорудний комбінат
Відкрите акціонерне товариство "Кар'єр мармуровий"
Закрите акціонерне товариство "Кар'єр мармуровий"
```

I want to extract everything **before "** and write to another file. I want the result to be:

```
Some other
Some other smth
Відкрите акціонерне товариство
Закрите акціонерне товариство
```

I have done this:

```
f=codecs.open('organization.txt','r+','utf-8')
text=f.read()
words_sp=text.split()
for line in text:
    before_keyword, after_keyword = line.split(u'"',1)
    before_word=before_keyword.split()[0]
    encoded=before_word.encode('cp1251')
    print encoded
```

But it doesn't work since there is a file lines that doesn't have **"**. How can I improve my code to make it work?

Comment: What do you expect the output to be? I find your explanation slightly ambiguous in this regard.

Comment: I have edited my post to make it clearer. I hope it is now quite good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems. First you must use the `splitlines()` function to break a string into lines. (What you have will iterate one character at a time.) Secondly, the following code will fail when split returns a single item:

```
before_keyword, after_keyword = line.split(u'"',1)
```

The following works for me:

```
for line in text.splitlines():
    if u'"' in line:
        before_keyword, after_keyword = line.split(u'"',1)
        ... etc. ...
```

Comment: It's a very great method but it doesn't work for me coz 'line.split(u'"',1)[0]' returns also all lines where there are no " ((

Comment: Could you help me again. I'm running this, but it returns blank lines. What is the reason?  
    'for line in text:'
        'if u'"' in line:'
            'before_keyword, after_keyword = line.split(u'"',1)'
            'encoded=before_keyword.encode('cp1251')'
            'print encoded'

Comment: I didn't notice before, but you need `for line in text.splitlines():`. Previously it was going through your text one character at a time. Answer updated.